# Appending Elements to Array

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, uitableview

I try to append elements to an array to later use that data and create a TableView as a Leaderboard.
I've already read through every post I could find but none of them worked out for me.

I have a Firebase Database where I get the UserData from. Here is the Node:

### [image: Firebase Node for a Single user]

Here you can see my class that handles this ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class LeaderboardViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var users:[User] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        load()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leaderCell") as! LeaderboardTableViewCell
        cell.placing.text = "\(indexPath.item+1)"
        cell.points.text = "\(indexPath.item + 20)"
        cell.name.text = "TestUser"
        return cell
    }

   func load(){
        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            for key in value!.allKeys{
                ref.child("\(key)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                    let userinfo = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                    let username = userinfo?.value(forKey: "username") as! String
                    let year = userinfo?.value(forKey: "year") as! String
                    let points = userinfo?.value(forKey: "points") as! Int

                    self.users.append(User(username: username, useryear: year, userpoints: points))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to retrieve the data when my ViewController "will load" so that when the view did appear I can reload the TableView Data. 
The Problem is, the data that I get won't get saved into the array.

I already tried initialising the array with 6+ elements but that didn't change anything. 
I also read that it could have something to do with the fact that I use a for-each loop but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a refresh as the call to get data from firebase is asynchronous

```
 self.users.append(User(username: username, useryear: year, userpoints: points)) 
 tableView.reloadData()
```

And

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    load() 
}
```

And remove `viewWillAppear` , since you have nested synonymous calls you can also make sue of `DispatchGroup` so the reload works when all requests are fulfilled

```
        let g = DispatchGroup()  /// 1
        for key in value!.allKeys{
            g.enter() /// 2
            ref.child("\(key)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                let userinfo = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                let username = userinfo?.value(forKey: "username") as! String
                let year = userinfo?.value(forKey: "year") as! String
                let points = userinfo?.value(forKey: "points") as! Int 
                self.users.append(User(username: username, useryear: year, userpoints: points))

                g.leave() //// 3
            }
        }

        g.notify(queue:.main) {  // 4
          tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally works. I guess i just sat on that for too long. Thanks again!